# Cakephp 3.0 new field not saving

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am new to php & cakephp. As in the example http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html. I have 3 tables bookmarks, tags, bookmarks_tags having bookmarkid, tagid. Using scaffolding process, I generated model, view, controllers for bookmarks and tags.  Now I added a new column "comments" to bookmarks_tags table. And modified my bookmarks/add view as below:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($bookmark) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Bookmark') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('url');
        echo $this->Form->input('bookmarks_tags._comments');
        echo $this->Form->input('tags._ids', ['options' => $tags]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

It is showing a comments textbox and saving all fields except comments.

I cleared tmp/cache/models folder but that is not helping!

Comment: The structure you've described lets you associate a comment with each bookmark+tag pair. That is, if you select three tags for the bookmark, you can have a comment for each of the three. And a different comment when you select one or more of those tags for a different bookmark. Is that the intent? Because the `tags._ids` form of input will allow you to select multiple tags, but there's no way with this to attach a comment to one of them. If that's the structure you want, it will take a different type of input layout. Plus, you need to drop the `_` from the start of comments on the input...

Comment: This helped. Thanks